# How do I change selected text's font in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I set the font of selected text in Outlook's HTML editor? I found a couple of answers on google, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Outlook are you using? In case of Outlook 2010 and up, Outlook always uses the Word editor and you can access it Application.ActiveExplorer.WordEditor, which returns an instance of the Word's Document object. Once you have it, you can use the Word object model to change the selected text attributes.